# Automatic log each session from Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, ssh

Just moved off from windows into a Mac. I used to use Putty and it has a feature of logging sessions into a folder so everything that happens (stdin/out) goes also to a folder for historic record.
I would like to have the same thing with Mac Terminal app.

Comment: I’m guessing you use putty to connect over ssh to other computers and need that logged? Can you refine if you need everything local to be logged or just ssh sessions off your Mac? Also, why not use putty on the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I am aware of:

1. Run all the commands you want in Terminal. Before closing the window go to *Shell* -> *Export Text As...* (or press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). This exports a text file with all the input and output of that session.
2. Start [`script`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) at the beginning of your session, e.g. with: `/usr/bin/script ~/Desktop/Terminal.log`. When you're done with the session type `exit` and a log file with all the input/output will be written (an example can be found in [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200642/435767)).

I found that the first method handles colours in the output better: it simply ignores it and writes the text to the file.
The `script` method writes control characters such as `[1m[0m[1m[36m` instead, which creates noise in your log. If you don't have any coloured output, that's no problem. If you do, perhaps there's an option for `script` that can handle this.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've seen `script` option around. I guess my question2 are 1. can I make it transparent of my work via `.zshrc`? and, 2. do I have to type exit? my work might include network disconnects and closing the lid without it...